# PHP splitting a URL, delimitted by a '='

Tags: php, html, split

Attempting to split the values after &file= for the following example URL. So i'm trying to extract the number at the end. Any suggestions?

http://blablablabla.com/test.php?type=mp4&tv=&file=3797

Comment: http://php.net/explode will do the trick

Comment: If I understood your question right, `$_GET['file']` to get the value of file. So it will get you 3797 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with many ways like using [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$query = parse_url('http://blablablabla.com/test.php?type=mp4&tv=&file=3797', PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $values);

print_r($values);
```

**output will be**

```
(
    [type] => mp4
    [tv] => 
    [file] => 3797
)
```

you can also do it with using regex like below

```
$str="http://blablablabla.com/test.php?type=mp4&tv=&file=3797";

preg_match_all('/([^?&=#]+)=([^&#]*)/',$str,$matched);

print_r($matched);
```

**output will be**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => type=mp4
            [1] => tv=
            [2] => file=3797
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => type
            [1] => tv
            [2] => file
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => mp4
            [1] => 
            [2] => 3797
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this along with the sanitize.

```
$file=filter_input(INPUT_GET, "file", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) // This will get the data and clean the data too.
```

If you don't need the sanitize, you can simply use it as,

`$file=$_GET['file']`

**I personally recommend the first method.**

Comment: What sanitation is done?